# why are the other classes not toggling?

Tags: javascript

I have tried to implement a class toggle solution proposed in a prior question that I had asked and it was a great solution but when I tried to implement it on other classes the other ones are not working and I cant figure  out why.

I have double checked any spelling mistake and tried to do a smaller scale code and found that it works just fine.

```js
var click = 0
var bbtn = 0

var top2 = document.getElementById("top2");
var swoop3 = document.getElementById("swoop3");
var swoop4 = document.getElementById("swoop4");
var title2 = document.getElementById("title2");
var backbtn = document.getElementById("backbtn");

top2.onclick = function() {
    top2.classList.toggle("on");
    title2.classList.toggle("on");
    swoop3.classList.toggle("on");
    swoop4.classList.toggle("on");
}
```

```css
.top2{
    background-color:orange;
    position:fixed;
    top:25%;
    left:0;
    height:25%;
    width:100%;
    border-top-left-radius:45px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
    border-bottom-style:outset;
    border-width:5px;
    transition: height .5s, top .5s,border-bottom-left-radius.5s,border-top-left-radius.5s;
}
.top2.on{
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
}
   
.title2{
    color:white;
    font-size:40px;
    position:fixed;
    top:34%;
    left:25%;
    animation-name:title2;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-delay:1s;
    animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    opacity:0;
    transition:top .5s;
}
.title2.on{
    top:5%;
}

@keyframes title2{
    100%{
        opacity:1;
    }
    
}
/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
.swoop3{
    background-color:orange;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:90%;
    height:52px;
    width:50px;
    transition:top .5s, height .5s;
}
.swoop3.on{
    top:100%;
}
/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
.swoop4{
    background-color:white;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:90%;
    height:52px;
    width:50px;
    border-top-right-radius:50px;
    border-top-style:inset;
    border-width:5px;
    transition:top .5s;
}
.swoop4.on{
    top:0;
}
```

I want everything to toggle when clicked but only top2 toggles and nothing else

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). With that code, it should be toggling all of them. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: In your javascript you refer to top2 as an id but in your style you are referring to it as a class. In CSS change `.top2` to `#top2`

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to say about your problem as you didn't provide an example of your HTML view. But there are two thing you have to check on your code.

- If your HTML elements don't have the id you're specifying in your javascript like `top2` or `swoop3` I recomend you add them first in all your elements the way you want like this:

  `<div id="top2"></div>`
- Once you have that, you should also change your css styles to point to the elements by their id. Meaning that instead of writing `.top2` you should write it as `#top2`. You can read more information about css selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). As a result, your css should look like this:

  `.top2 {
       background-color:orange;
       // ... other styles
   }
   .top2.on {
       // ... more styles
   }`